# HHVM Assistance

Tags: facebook, cygwin, hhvm

I have a problem installing HHVM on windows using Cygwin64 Terminal 
 
I'm using this guide https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-Installing-HHVM-on-Cygwin

 It's an official guide, as you can see, I've reached **Building libmemcached** step, after executing the command **./configure --prefix=/usr && make -j 4 && make install** it does many commands but It reaches this error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Mr.gSub/hhvm/libmemcached-1.0.18'
make[2]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Mr.gSub/hhvm/libmemcached-1.0.18'
make -j2  man
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Mr.gSub/hhvm/libmemcached-1.0.18'
make[2]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Mr.gSub/hhvm/libmemcached-1.0.18'
make -j2  man
```

And it keeps going that way until I terminate, I will include all log in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/MFwXJx6S

I'm using Windows 8.1 x64, my shoe size is 41.. yeah I don't think you need that much of info :P haha, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

HHVM does not currently build on Windows. Your best option is to run an Ubuntu VM and have HHVM running inside that.

Comment: But why would they have that guide on Cygwin64 ?

Comment: Cygwin support was never finished, and that guide hasn't been touched since February. Even if it worked at the time, it is extremely out of date by now.